# Batch find and replacing text between parentheses

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I need to replace the text after `HOST =`  with a user input in my text file with pure batch.
The name `VM-TEST` is not always the same and can change because this will be used in multiple files.
I'm stuck here.

Text example:

> ```
> (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = VM-TEST)(PORT = 1521))
> ```

All I got is this:

```
@echo off &setlocal
set "search=host ="
set "replace=HOST = test"
set "textfile=Input.txt"
set "newfile=Output.txt"
(for /f "delims=" %%i in (%textfile%) do (
    set "line=%%i"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set "line=!line:%search%=%replace%!"
    echo(!line!
    endlocal
))>"%newfile%"
del %textfile%
rename %newfile%  %textfile%
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey :) I've built a little script that should do the job.
It splits up the properties on the opening bracket first, so you can then check if it matches the property you are looking for. This is done using findstr /r and therefore makes it possible for you to write simple regular expressions as search string. Your name "VM-TEST" is represented as ".*" in the regex, so it can be any string.

```
@echo off & setlocal
set "search=host = .*)"
set "replace=HOST = test)"
set "textfile=in.txt"
set "newfile=out.txt"
del "%newfile%" 2>nul

for /f "usebackq delims=" %%L in ("%textfile%") do (
    call :replaceProperty "%%~L"
)

del "%textfile%"
rename "%newfile%" "%textfile%"
exit

:replaceProperty
set "_remainingLine=%~1"
set "_outputLine="

:replaceProperty_while
    if "%_remainingLine%"=="" goto break

    if "%_remainingLine:~0,1%"=="(" (
        rem this needs to be checked additionally as for /f skips empty tokens
        set "_outputLine=%_outputLine%("
        set "_remainingLine=%_remainingLine:~1%"
        goto replaceProperty_while
    )

    for /F "tokens=1* delims=(" %%q in ("%_remainingLine%") do (
        echo:%%q|findstr /i /r /c:"^%search%$">nul 
        if errorlevel 1 (
            set "_outputLine=%_outputLine%%%q"
        ) else (
            set "_outputLine=%_outputLine%%replace%"
        )

        if "%%r"=="" (
            goto break
        ) else (
            set "_remainingLine=(%%r"
        )
    )
goto replaceProperty_while

:break
    rem Finished processing the line. Write output and exit subroutine.
    rem This can't be done in the if-block because the output line will contain brackets.
    echo:%_outputLine%>>"%newfile%"
exit /b
```

This is a sample file I used for testing:

```
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = VM-TEST)(PORT = 1521))
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = Something_else)(PORT = 1521))
this line won't get modified
(this works as well but
trailing brackets will get lost though (
((some other stuff = (text) ))
((HOST = VM-TEST)(PORT = 1521)(PROTOCOL = TCP))
```

Edit #1,2: Updated code for leading whitespace support and performance improvements.

Edit #3: I assume that every line in your file contains at least one space, but if you want that empty lines don't get lost, you can replace the first `for /f "usebackq ...` loop with this one:

```
for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%K in ('findstr /n /r "^" "%textfile%"') do (
    call :replaceProperty "%%~L"
)
```

Comment: I want to add User input into set "replace=HOST = test)" where the "test" part is the user input from the CMD window. I tried set "replace=HOST = %hostname%)"
set /P HostName="HostName:" any suggestions ?

Comment: i got it working now. the last problem is it takes the format for example tab stops out of the file which is very important

Comment: @RebornOG Tabs work fine for me, can you give me an example file where characters get lost?

Comment: here is the example file where tabs get lost. its before they get deleted. https://pastebin.com/5XzAJqfx

Comment: Leading whitespace indeed gets eaten by the current version. This is because of the well known behaviour of `set/p` which removes all leading whitespace. You can work around that with backspace characters... but I think it would be much easier and faster to completely avoid writing the file with `set/p`. I'm working on a solution and will update my answer as soon as I'm finished with it.

Comment: thank you ! this works very well :) is there a way to do for example "goto file2" and then just do the same procedure for a second file ?

Comment: The code at Edit #3 is not correct, `findstr /n /r $ "%textfile%"` would let you lose the last line of the input file if it is not terminated by a CR+LF sequence (since `$` anchors to CR); you should use `findstr /N "^" "%textfile%"` instead…

Comment: @RebornOG Yes, the easiest way imo would be to replace the manually set file variable `set "textfile=in.txt"` by a parameter like `%1`. This way you could call the batch script for every file or just drop a file on it in the explorer. You can also move the loop into the batch file, so you can give it more parameters at once (or predefine all files).

Comment: @aschipfl Thank you, I forgot about that. Code is fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following script:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_ROOT=D:\Target" & rem // (path to target directory)
set "_IFILE=Input.txt" & rem // (name of input file)
set "_OFILE=Output.txt" & rem // (name of output file)
set "_SEARCH=HOST" & rem // (keyword to search for)
set /P _REPLAC="Enter new HOST value: " & rem // (replacement value)

rem // Gather horizontal tabulator (TAB) character:
for /F "delims=" %%T in ('forfiles /P "%~dp0." /M "%~nx0" /C "cmd /C echo/0x09"') do set "_TAB=%%T"

rem // Write to output file:
> "%_ROOT%\%_OFILE%" (
    rem /* Read from input file line by line, precede each line with line number + `:`
    rem    in order not to appear empty to `for /F` and therefore not to be skipped: */
    for /F "delims=" %%L in ('findstr /N "^" "%_ROOT%\%_IFILE%"') do (
        rem // Store current line, reset line buffer:
        set "LINE=%%L" & set "COLL=("
        rem // Toggle delayed expansion to avoid trouble with `!`:
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        rem // Remove temporary line number + `:` prefix:
        set "LINE=!LINE:*:=!"
        rem // Skip processing of an empty line:
        if defined LINE (
            rem // Skip processing of a line that contains `*`, `?`, `<`, `>`:
            if "!LINE!"=="!LINE:**=!" if "!LINE!"=="!LINE:*?=!" if "!LINE!"=="!LINE:*<=!" if "!LINE!"=="!LINE:*>=!" (
                rem // Temporarily double `"`:
                set "LINE=!LINE:"=""!^"
                rem // Split line at every `(` and loop through the items:
                for %%I in ("!LINE:(=" "!") do (
                    endlocal
                    rem // Store current item:
                    set "ITEM=%%~I"
                    rem // Split item into keyword and remainder:
                    for /F "tokens=1* delims==%_TAB% " %%G in ("%%~I") do (
                        rem // Check whether keyword matches:
                        if /I "%%G"=="%_SEARCH%" (
                            rem // Split off `)` and everything behind from remainder:
                            set "REST=%%H"
                            setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
                            for /F "tokens=1* delims=)" %%E in ("!REST:)=)(!") do (
                                endlocal
                                rem // Rebuild new item with replacement value:
                                set "ITEM=%%G = %_REPLAC%)%%F"
                                setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
                            )
                            endlocal
                        )
                    )
                    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
                    rem // Revert doubling `"`:
                    if defined ITEM set "ITEM=!ITEM:""="!^"
                    rem /* Append item to line buffer;
                    rem    transport result beyond `endlocal`: */
                    if defined ITEM set "ITEM=!ITEM:(=!"
                    for /F "delims=" %%K in ("!COLL!(!ITEM!") do (
                        endlocal
                        set "COLL=%%K"
                        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
                    )
                )
                set "LINE=!COLL:~2!"
            )
        )
        rem // Return resulting line:
        echo(!LINE!
        endlocal
    )
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

The following restrictions apply:

- the keyword to search for must not contain `=`, <kbd>SPACE</kbd>, <kbd>TAB</kbd>, `(`, `)`;
- the given keyword to search (like `HOST`) is treated case-**in**sensitively (to change that, remove the `/I` option from `if /I "%%G"=="%_SEARCH%"`);
- lines that contain the keyword to search (like `HOST`) must not contain any of the characters `*`, `?`, `<`, `>`; if they do, the desired replacement is not performed;
- the original sequence of white-spaces around the `=`-sign in the replaced string portion (like `HOST = VM-TEST`) is not maintained, it always is the keyword + <kbd>SPACE</kbd> + `=` + <kbd>SPACE</kbd> + the replacement value;

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that! What is the specific problem? I just tried to fix an issue (see my edited code), but I'm currently on mobile, so I still can't test the script at the moment…

Comment: After finally testing the script I fixed a minor issue (see [rev. 6](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/63923902/6)), and then I improved it to be able to no longer skip empty lines, to handle TABs and to no longer lose partial strings upon occurrence of the characters `*`, `?`, `<`, `>`…

Comment: thank you for your help ! this seems to work. i need the file name to be kept the same after running the script tho.

Comment: Well, this shouldn't be a problem, should it? put `move /Y "%_ROOT%\%_OFILE%" "%_ROOT%\%_IFILE%" > nul` in a new line before the final `endlocal`…